# Django UpdateView without form to update object

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using class based views with django 1.9 and I am trying to figure out how to update an object(After clicking a button) without using the form. I do not need any user input to update the object. Can you help me?

In models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
stateID = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
isOpen = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether the registration is open.', verbose_name='active')

def __unicode__(self):
    return bool(self.isOpen)
```

In views.py

```
class OpenTournament(View):
    model = State

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = State.objects.all()

        if queryset.count() != 1:
            State(stateID=1, isOpen=True).save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success_url/')

        else:
            #need to update the table from a button click
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/updated/")
```

Comment: We need a little bit more context. Do you want to update the object through an AJAX call? Please update the question with all the details in order to get a response.

Comment: You need to post the code and the error.

Comment: There is a table with a boolean field in my models.py. I need to change that field's value from a button click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That does not help at all. **You need to show the code**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Edited the question with the code.

Comment: Thanks but I am still not sure what you are asking. What are you unable to do in that code? You know how to get an item and save it, so where is the problem?

Comment: If the 'State' table already has an object, I want to change its 'isOpen' field's value to True.

Comment: Here u should send the request through ajax, go through doc https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html  maybe helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I found it. Access the State by primary key

```
open = State.objects.get(id=1)
open.isOpen = True
post.save()
```